# Xceed property grid - [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)] attribute not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, propertygrid, xceed

I have a class which has properties, based on selecting one item in the combobox property, other properties will be shown or hidden. I am using [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)] for the combobox property. 
Class which is bound to the property grid:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(PropertySubsetConverter<FileSystemOperation>))]
 public class FileSystemOperation : IPropertySubsetObject
 { 
    [Description("File system operations like Copy, Move, Delete & Check file.")]
    [Category("Mandatory")]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    public Op Operation { get; set; }

 public enum Op
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Copy file
  /// </summary>
  CopyFile,
  /// <summary>
  /// Move file
  /// </summary>
  MoveFile,
  /// <summary>
  /// Delete file
  /// </summary>
  DeleteFile,
  /// <summary>
  /// Delete directory
  /// </summary>
  DeleteDirectory,
  /// <summary>
  /// Check if file exists
  /// </summary>
  ExistFile
}
 }
```

if user select 'DeleteDirectory', below property should be shown and other properties should be hidden

```
[AppliesTo(Op.DeleteDirectory)]
public bool Recursive { get; set; }
```

My Xaml:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="pk"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="ExtraBold" IsEnabled="{Binding PropertyGridIsEnabled}"  SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedElement, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="#FF4A5D80" Foreground="White"/>
```

This works with Winform property grid, but not working with Xceed wpf property grid. Need help if I am missing any property to set.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with modifying the `ReadOnly` attribute of a property. WinForm PropertyGrid works, Xceed PropertyGrid doesn't. May be the paid Plus version would work. It has a `DependsOn` attribute.

I solved it using the PropertyGrid's `PropertyValueChanged` event.

```
private void propertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged(object sender, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // get the descriptor of the changed property
    PropertyDescriptor propDesc = ((PropertyItem)e.OriginalSource).PropertyDescriptor;

    // try to get the RefreshPropertiesAttribute
    RefreshPropertiesAttribute attr
        = (RefreshPropertiesAttribute)propDesc.Attributes[typeof(RefreshPropertiesAttribute)];

    // if the attribute exists and it is set to All
    if (attr != null && attr.RefreshProperties == RefreshProperties.All)
    {
        // invoke PropertyGrid.UpdateContainerHelper
        MethodInfo updateMethod = propertyGrid.GetType().GetMethod(
            "UpdateContainerHelper", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        updateMethod.Invoke(propertyGrid, new object[0]);
    }
}
```